# Gradle: build test classes even when tests are not executed

Tags: java, gradle, integration-testing

I have created an integration test task for my java project following [this guide](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-integration-testing/).

Omitting some irrelevant details, the task is like follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task integrationTests (type: Test){

  testClassesDir = sourcesets.integrationTests.outputClasesDir
  classpath = sourceSets.IntegrationTests.runtimeClasspath

}

sourceSets {
  integration {
     java { 
         //integration test sources
  }
}

configurations {
  integrationTestsCompile.extendsFrom. testCompile
  integrationTestsRuntime.extendsFrom  testRuntime
}

check.dependsOn integrationTests
```

This works perfectly except that now I need to split the test in two stages: unit tests in the build machines and integration tests in integration test machines (because they need some setup)

To make thinks more complicated, I cannot recompile code in the integration test machines, so I need to compile, but not executed integration test code in the build machines.

How can I do this? I've seen there's an integrationTestsClasses task that does the compilation, but I would like to call it automatically when building the project.

Thanks in advance